# Can a WM6 Emulator have a storage card?

Tags: windows-mobile, emulation

We're doing windows mobile development using the WM6 Professional emulator through visual studio 2008 for now. My question is, can you get the emulator image to simulate having a storage card? We run our SQLCE 3.5 database off the removable storage card in our devices and it'd be slick to just have the emulator simulate this situation as well. We've looked through the emulator configuration settings and didn't come across this option.

We've got the mobile devices sitting on the desk so we could always just deploy to them directly to solve this issue, but I figured it was worth polling the group anyhow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to setup a storage card for the emulator.

In the emulator window, goto File/Configure.  On the General tab there is a setting for Shared Folder.  You can point this at a directory on your host machine.  The directory will show up as a storage cord on the em.

Comment: You got it. We actually were playing around and figured this out. Thanks for the response! Works like a champ.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, yes the Storage card is emulated. Thought its good to always test on a real hardware device before releasing. I have found that sometimes the Storage Card on the emulator is not 100% consistent with hardware access. Actually, the emulator can be a bit buggy in this regard.

For example, I use SQLITE extensively in my PDA applications. Sometimes I cant get the emulator to create a new database file, even though the same code works perfectly on a device.

Point: Its great for testing, but will fail occasionally and if some code is not executing that you think should.... run it on a hardware device before wasting hours troubleshooting it on the emulator.

Comment: Actually I have a situation where VS2008 will refuse to deploy on the "Storage Card"(shared folder). The error I get is "The device is not ready" even though I can see the device from WMDC. But if I remove it-and allow the "Storage Card" to be created automatically during the deployment from VS, everything works perfectly; deployment is successful.